# Dense sets in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am attempting to prove the following statement:

"Let $X$ be a metric space and $A \subseteq X$. The following statements are equivalent:
(1) $A$ is dense in $X$.
(2) For every non-empty open set $U$, $U \cap A \not = \emptyset$.
(3) For every $x \in X$, there is a sequence $\{a_n\}$ from $A$ such that $a_n \to x$."

I'm totally stuck as to how to even start this, and the only definition of a dense set I have is that if $A \subseteq X$ is dense, then $\overline{A}=X$. Additionally, my only definition of closure is that $\overline{A}=\{x \in X \mid d(x,A)=0\}$.

Any tips would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Let me try to help you. What's the meaning of $\overline{A}=X$? Clue: For all $b\in X$ there exists...

Comment: My definition of closure is for all $x \in X$, $d(x,A)=0$.

Comment: And what's the meaning of $d(x,A)=0$?

Comment: $d(x,A)=0$ means that $x \in A$. Where would this set $U$ in question come from?

Comment: I think  it would be good if you add the definitions of closure and denseness in your question.

Comment: I added it to my question.

Comment: @bzoll213 $d(x,A)=0$ **does not** mean that $x\in A$. Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the standard distance and let $A$ be the interval $(-\infty, 1)$. Note that $d(1, A)=0$ even though $1\not\in A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in order to solve this we need to know what $d(x,A)$ means. By the definition

$$d(x,A)=\inf_{a\in A}\big\{d(x,a)\big\}$$

"(1) $\Rightarrow$ (2)" Assume there's a nonempty open subset $U\subseteq X$ such that $U\cap A=\emptyset$. Since we are in a metric spaces then we can choose $u\in U$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $B(u,r)\subseteq U$, where $B(u,r)$ is the open ball around $u$ of radius $r$. Since $U\cap A=\emptyset$ then $d(u,a)\geq r$ for any $a\in A$. Therefore $u\not\in\overline{A}$. Contradiction.

"(2) $\Rightarrow$ (3)" Let $x\in X$. By (2) we have $B(x,r)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ for any $r>0$. Define $a_n$ to be any element of $B(x,1/n)\cap A$. Note that $a_n\to x$ and $a_n\in A$.

"(3) $\Rightarrow$ (1)" Let $x\in X$. We will show that $x\in\overline{A}$. By (3) there is a sequence $(a_n)\subseteq A$ convergent to $x$. Therefore $d(x,a_n)\to 0$ and so $\inf_{n} d(x,a_n)=0$. Thus $d(x,A)=0$ and so $x$ belongs to the closure of $A$.